# List of current mini fridge makes/models that will fit 5-gallon kegs?

Tags: kegerator, refrigerator

Any fellow homebrewers out there have a suggestion on a current make/model minifridge (not full-sized fridge or chest freezer) that will fit 5-gallon corny kegs?  I've seen many suggestions of Frigidaire FRC445GB and Sanyo 4912M models but, like many others referenced online, they seem to be no longer manufactured.

I'm looking for something simply to fit 2 corny kegs and a 5 lb CO2 tank.  What is currently available that I can buy new if my repeated searches for old models in want ads and Craigslist continue to be fruitless?

Comment: A suggestion:  Look at the kegerator vendors...some of them do conversions, in theory they would show at least a brand you could research.

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought the "Danby 4.4 cu. ft. Designer Series Compact All-Refrigerator" from hhgregg (http://www.hhgregg.com/ProductDetail.asp?SID=n&ProductID=16331).  It works well but be advised you can only fit 2 kegs if you're using the taller/skinnier ones (8.5" diameter).  Typically the ball lock kegs are this size.

Someone posted some details for converting this particular fridge on the Northern Brewer forum:  http://forum.northernbrewer.com/viewtopic.php?t=65288